# I'm tryeing to include partial header.ejs and footer.ejs In AWS cloud 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, include, partials, aws-cloud9

after i have try so many times to find a solutions i'm asking some help when i try <% include partials/header.ejs  %> with AWS cloud 9 it gives a error i have created the files for header named header.ejs and footer.ejs inside of directory partials that have parent direct views.

something like this

## This is the home page

Answer (score 0):

Try using this new syntax instead of the old one.

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>)
```

You can use similar syntax for the footer.